# Let $\{(X_n, d_n)\}$ be a sequence of metric spaces, and let $X=\prod X_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For each $x = \{x_n\}$ and $y = \{y_n\}$ in $X$, define $d(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,y_n)}$.

b. Show that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space iff each $(X_n, d_n)$ is complete.

c. Show that $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space iff each $(X_n, d_n)$ is compact.

I just need a hint for b and c. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are your thoughts? Also, the definition of $d$ seems incorrect. Indeed, taking $X_n=\mathbb{R}$, $x_n=0$, and $y_n=1$ for every $n$, then $d(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/2$ does not converge.

Comment: @JohnGriffin maybe there must be a sequence $a_n$ in the summation  such that $\Sigma |a_n| < \infty$

Comment: @Lo12 ...as JohnGriffin pointed out,the first statement might be wrong..and secondly you do not offend me but this site

Comment: I suggest getting a bounty for this one.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Yes it seems I forgot a piece of the definition. Let me edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be useful to first prove that a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements in $X$ converges to $x$ if and only if $(x_n(k))_n$ converges to $x(k)$ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

From here (b) should follow from the definition of completeness and (c) should follow using the fact that a metric space is compact iff it is sequentially compact.